# Fullcalendar not working in FF on a windows machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, fullcalendar

I have a problem of dragging and dropping external elements to a calendar (Fullcalendar) on a windows machine. All works fine on a linux, mac machine. But does not save to the database on a windows machine. What may be the problem??

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* initialize the external events
       -----------------------------------------------------------------
    */

jQuery('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
    title: jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    jQuery(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    jQuery(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });
});

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        loading: function(bool) { 
            if (bool) jQuery('#loading').show(); 
            else jQuery('#loading').hide(); 
        }, 

        events: "/roster/manage/ajax?part=shiftcalendar&nodeID="+placeid,


        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev,next today',
        },

        cache: false,   
    editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = jQuery(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    // Call this function to store the date and time of this shift into a table
            saveShift(originalEventObject,copiedEventObject);
    },

        eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {

            if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to change dates?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            else {
                // Our edit function for this shift
                updateShift(event);
            }
        },

        eventClick: function(event,revertFunc) {
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this "+ event.title +" shift?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            else {
                // Delete shift
                deleteShift(event);    
            }
        }


        /*eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

            jQuery.getJSON('/roster/manage/ajax', {part: "shiftcalendarpeople", shiftID: event.id }, function(data) {
                if(data != null) {
                    var layer = "<div id='events_"+event.id+"'>";
                        jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
                            layer += "<span>"+v.user+" as "+v.role+"</span>";
                        });
                    layer += "</div>";
                    jQuery(this).append(layer);
                }
                else {

                    var layer = "<div id='events_"+event.id+"'><span>No people rostered.</span></div>";
                    jQuery(this).append(layer);
                }
            });

        },

        eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            jQuery("#events_"+event.id+"").remove();
        }*/

    })
});
```

Comment: Could you describe your issue in greater detail? Is your problem that `saveShift` does not fire? Or does it fire but your code to save the event doesn't work? Does firebug show the AJAX request to save? Does the address look alright? What is the response? Can you catch the request when debugging your serverside code? As far as I can tell the actual dragging and dropping works on my windows machine, in my version of firefox, [using this code](http://jsfiddle.net/x6EXE/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something works on every machine except windows (or vice-versa) it's because of path issues. I see that you use a unix path in a variable

events: "/roster/manage/ajax?part=shiftcalendar&nodeID="+placeid

Maybe try using the windows style path "\roster\manage\ajax?part=shiftcalendar&nodeID="+placeid

It's a rough guess. It's what jumps to my eyes at first glance.

Comment: it's double backslash, the post changed to single backslash on it's own